# Google Sheets IMPORTXML div class not working

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Hey I've been playing around with IMPORTXML and I have successfully pulled back some data on eBay but ran across an issues I can't seem to resolve nor find similar examples to try

Here's what I have listed in Google Sheets as the IMPORTXML.  It returns a #NA.

`=IMPORTXML("https://www.ebay.com/sh/research?marketplace=EBAY-US&keywords=1989+Upper+Deck+Griffey+Jr+%22PSA+9%22&dayRange=90&endDate=1693576463117&startDate=1430504463117&categoryId=0&offset=0&limit=50&sorting=datelastsold&tabName=SOLD&tz=America%2FDenver","//div[@class='metric-value']")`

It's unclear to me why this wouldn't work. Thanks in advance.